# Eliminate NavigationLink button shape in accessibility mode

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a small SwiftUI project that supports "Button Shapes" in accessibility mode.
[image: Button Shapes in accessibility mode]
But I found that when I enable this mode, there is a small white rectangle in the center of the screen, which I guess is the NavigationLink I put for SecondView.
Here is my code:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var activeSecondView = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("FirstView")
                Button("Tap to show second view") {
                    self.activeSecondView = true
                }
            }
            .overlay(NavigationLink(destination: Text("SecondView"), isActive: $activeSecondView) {EmptyView()})
        }
    }
}
```

And it runs like this(The redundant rectangle is circled in red):
[image: Extra tappable area in the center]

Is there any way to eliminate or hide this small white rectangle while "Button Shapes" is enable?

Comment: Try to put link into background instead of overlay.

Comment: I tried it but still not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next (not tested just idea)

```
.background(
   NavigationLink(destination: Text("SecondView"), isActive: $activeSecondView) 
       {EmptyView()}.opacity(0)          // << this !!
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("SecondView"), isActive: $activeSecondView) 
   {EmptyView()}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) //this solve the problem
```

Comment: Better use `.buttonStyle(.plain)`, it does the same thing, but looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a solution by myself, not sure if this is the best practice. Anyway I will share it in case any one encounters similar problem.
Just hide the NavigationLink behind the main content and it will become invisible:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var activeSecondView = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("SecondView"), isActive: $activeSecondView) {EmptyView()}
                Color.white
                VStack {
                    Text("FirstView")
                    Button("Tap to show second view") {
                        self.activeSecondView = true
                    }
                }
            }
            //.background(NavigationLink(destination: Text("SecondView"), isActive: $activeSecondView) {EmptyView()})
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I recently encountered the same problem, except my View had many NavigationLinks grouped together and they used a ton of space, plus you are able to tap them and that might cause behaviors we don't want.

The solution I found was grouping my NavigationLinks inside a `ZStack` and setting its opacity to 0 (`.opacity(0)`). The `ZStack` reduces the space into just one button (I didn't find a way to remove this space without major refactoring to my current navigation unfortunately), and the opacity set to 0 makes it so you cannot press on them anymore (of course, navigation still works if your using `isActive:` or `tag:`).

Extra detail: this issue seems to starts happening on iOS 15. I tested on iOS 14.5 and the NavigationLinks acted as normal